# Not able to update .properties file value via maven command

Tags: maven, junit4, rest-assured

I have global.properties file like:-
baseUrl=${baseUrl}

While sending the command mvn test -DbaseUrls getting error:
Error:-

[ERROR] Errors:

[ERROR]   parameterValue cannot be null

[ERROR]   Illegal character in path at index 1: ${baseUrl}

[INFO]

Pom.xml is:

Comment: pom.xml is  :- <properties>

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>

<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

<baseUrl>defaultURLValue</baseUrl>

</properties>

Answer (score 0):

If you need define properties in external file, please use [Properties Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html)